# Cannot update existing entries in the database

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use Entity Framework Core (C# with ASP .NET Core) to update entries in the database (PostgreSQL) when an entry with an Id already exists, but this does not work:

```
     public async Task SaveFileInfos(FileInfo fileInfo)
     {
        var foundFileInfo = _context.FileInfos.Where(f => f.FileId ==fileInfo.FileId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (foundFileInfo == null)
        {
            await _context.FileInfos.AddAsync(fileInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            _context.FileInfos.Update(fileInfo);
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

By the way, the Id cannot be a GUID because it has to be 34 digits long.

```
public class FileInfo : IFileInfo
{
    [Key]
    public string FileId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to change an already contained entry I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'FileInfo' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'FileId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NullableKeyIdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Update(TEntity entity)
```

What am I doing wrong ? It must be a beginner's mistake ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF makes updates of the entities being tracked. In this case *foundFileInfo* is the entity tracked, and for EF *fileInfo* is a new entry.

So if you want to update the entry try to use the entity tracked. E.g:

```
public async Task SaveFileInfos(FileInfo fileInfo)
 {
    var foundFileInfo = _context.FileInfos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FileId == fileInfo.FileId);

    if (foundFileInfo == null)
    {
        await _context.FileInfos.AddAsync(fileInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        foundFileInfo.FileName = fileInfo.FileName;
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Cool, your suggestion works, thanks, you have just really helped a beginner :-)